# Obtaining Transit Spectrum for Celestial Bodies Using JWST NIRSPEC

Tags: observational-astronomy, spectroscopy, spectra, python, james-webb-space-telescope

I've recently been tasked with obtaining transit spectrum data for some fascinating celestial bodies, including Ceres, Enceladus, Ganymede, Io, and Titan. The goal is to compare their transit spectra with that of Earth. However, I'm facing a bit of a challenge when it comes to using the GitHub package here: https://github.com/nespinoza/transitspectroscopy

To provide some context, I've received instructions to utilize the GitHub package to gather the transit spectrum data. However, I'm not very familiar with how to effectively use it for this purpose. Despite my best efforts, I haven't been able to navigate the package successfully to retrieve the transit spectrum data that I need.

If any of you have experience with the Github package or if you know of alternative methods to obtain transit spectrum data for these celestial bodies, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Perhaps you can share some step-by-step instructions or valuable resources that could help me get started.

Moreover, if there are any other tools or platforms that you've found helpful for collecting transit spectrum data, I'd be open to exploring those options as well.

If it would help, here are the links to the files of the celestial objects that I'm supposed to compare their transit spectra against Earth's:
[Io](https://mast.stsci.edu/viz/ui/#/spectra?uri=mast%3AJWST%2Fproduct%2Fjw01373-o024_t007_nirspec_g395h-f290lp_s3d.fits), [Ceres](https://mast.stsci.edu/viz/ui/#/spectra?uri=mast%3AJWST%2Fproduct%2Fjw01244-o001_t001_nirspec_g395h-f290lp_s3d.fits), [Titan](https://mast.stsci.edu/viz/ui/#/spectra?uri=mast%3AJWST%2Fproduct%2Fjw01251-o004_t002_nirspec_g395h-f290lp_s3d.fits), [Enceladus](https://mast.stsci.edu/viz/ui/#/spectra?uri=mast%3AJWST%2Fproduct%2Fjw01250-o006_t002_nirspec_g395h-f290lp_s3d.fits), [Ganymede1](https://mast.stsci.edu/viz/ui/#/spectra?uri=mast%3AJWST%2Fproduct%2Fjw01373-o019_t001_nirspec_g395h-f290lp_s3d.fits), [Ganymede2](https://mast.stsci.edu/viz/ui/#/spectra?uri=mast%3AJWST%2Fproduct%2Fjw01373-o028_t001_nirspec_g395h-f290lp_s3d.fits)

Comment: What have you tried so far and how far have you gotten? Do you have Python set-up? Did you install the package? Did you try to use it?
Basically, the package contains a library that you can include into your own code to do all sorts of things. The methods that it provides are documented in the source code and your IDE should assist you in using them, once you have successfully imported the library into your Python project.

Comment: I've downloaded the repository and extracted the files. However, I'm not sure how to access them and how to make them work for my specific analysis. I have only run so far the files in the tests folder to see if it works. As of now, I'm figuring out how to integrate the data files mentioned above. I haven't made a Python project for it because I assumed that the package can directly process the data file through a terminal or in a Python IDE. I've reviewed the source code a bit, and I see that the package provides various methods. I'm currently using Ubuntu and Python Anaconda.